# Performance differences with 4 memory sticks vs. 2 sticks?

Tags: memory, performance

Is there a performance difference between 2 memory sticks of 8 GB vs. 4 sticks of 4GB?

The motherboard has *max 32GB capacity*.

The computer configuration can be seen below.
[image: list of components]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a motherboard with two memory channels, having one memory stick on each channel will usually be very slightly faster than having two memory sticks on each channel because one fewer command state is needed.

Comment: sorry for the novice question: how many channels does my motherboard support?
so basically your answer is that i better use 2 of 8GB then 4 of 4GB yes?

Comment: Your memory controller is on your CPU and it has two channels. Yes, 2x8 is a better choice.

Comment: thanks pal, can u say a word about the computer above?
it's a computer for heady duty tasks for a programmer. 
where do you spot a bottle neck..?

Comment: @arik A 1TB main drive and 120GB SSD is kind of skimpy these days, but other than that I don't see a problem.